# Bodhicitta and the path of knives?

Tags: rebirth, bodhisattva

Is cutting off the "path of knives" (i.e. avoiding rebirth into lower realms) not the ultimate?

I mean, obviously it's unlikely any Buddhist seeker would affirm that. But, given life on earth can be improved for humans, is it not very *like* the ultimate, to never again accrue evil karma and rebirth into hell or animal or ghost realms?

Also, do any of the schools which say some sentient beings lack a seed for buddhahood, self enlightenment, and arhatship, claim that those sentient beings can forever avoid rebirth into the evil destinies? 
And in what way can they work for bodhicitta?

Comment: if anyone can remember the name for that seed, then let me know in a comment. thanks.

Comment: I think that's called "Buddha seed" (佛種), or "Bodhi seed" (菩提種). It is said that contacting serious wrong *fake* teachings could cause permanent damage of that seed. Although it's the first sentence Buddha exclaimed when 1st arisen from his enlightenment that historical morning after seeing the stars, that "all beings are already with the Buddha nature (seed)..."

Comment: @Mishu米殊 Is that *[tathāgatagarbha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tath%C4%81gatagarbha_s%C5%ABtras)*?

Comment: in a loose sense you may say that. Tathagatagarbha, Buddha-nature, Bodhi... talking about "that" in different perspectives maybe - but perspectives do matter, ChrisW

Answer (score 2):

The aim should not to be to avoid reincarnation in 'lower' realms, but to alleviate suffering for all sentient beings. Please do keep that in mind. Focusing on reincarnation encourages selfish thinking.

Comment: hm well ofc i don't disagree but there's merit before there is bodhicitta etc

Answer (score 1):

Good if asking not for them, but for yourself first! What does it require that a desire for awakening whould arise in me? Bodhicitta, unsakeable.

When wise speak how incredibly seldom a human existance is, people are for the most incapable to imagen. Why? Because they see permanent in what is impermanent, believing that all they experiance is their own. Signs, sounds, smell, taste, touch and thoughts: the world.
But it might for those be possible to imagen how seldom a live not stupid, living in a civilized country and meeting even the good teachings of the/a Buddha is, given how seldom such one appears in this world.

Just that, imagen it proper, putting on honest meassures, one is properbly cabaple, if not stupid, to understand such as the [highest blessings](http://www.zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/kn/snp/snp.2.04.than_en.html).

If, when understanding this, seeing that one is for now not blessed in this or that point, then to seek for that, to nurish it, that would be possible cause that it might arise one time for one.

For those who, if meeting such auspicious blessings but get not aware that those are not for sure, will not last in ways of that they might come in touch with teachings telling them, that they own inherent goodness or inherent capacities, a seed, or a nature, a tendency, yet having not [entered the stream](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/study/into_the_stream_en.html), are total insecure, open to all evil and pain for long long time: What do you think, are they blessed? Who ever could help them, if they whould not give the causes and conditions by themselves?

[Why it is important to value our Conditions?](http://sangham.net/index.php/topic,172.0.html)

So each of you would do good to reflect wise and deeply if, now if so gifted, is it really smart to believe now others than the Buddha and those thinking even to know it better of what he thought behind simple words?

Is it wise to listen to those who for themselves are not able to renounce, still hold on everything, still hold on home, kind... still possessed with all fetters, living like you intrade and dependency, or whould you, reflecting on the [kalama sutta](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/an/an03/an03.065.than_en.html), not be wiser to tend to those who have left normal ways of life, if seeking advice?

All my person is able to give here, are some small [doors for freedom of "Buddha nature"](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/thanissaro/freedomfrombuddhanature_en.html).

If you are capable to get (take) the message, is totally up to your conditions of wish [association](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/ptf/dhamma/sacca/sacca4/samma-ditthi/kalyanamittata_en.html) is the most importand, the only real importand outwardly condition, so here you are: alone as before, but maybe now with a small light for refuge.

Study just this tiny but very deep, very deep short sutta, here rendered and commented by a nearly 90 years old dutch living Bodhisatta, [Upasika Nina](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/index_en.html#vangorkom) Van Gorkum: [The Greatest Blessings](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/vangorkom/greatestblessing_en.html)

The Maha Mangala Sutta contains all for your good journey, where ever you desire to arrive.

If you after having read and possibly [listen](http://sangham.net/index.php?action=tpmod;dl=get523), do not experiance tears running from your face, then remember those gifted who experianced it.

May you, may all beings, be blessed with the highest gift!

It's really time and urgend to leave the path of knives and imagen how long one used so many others and pain, to condinue it for selfish sakes, "cheated", "insane".

*[Note: This is a gift of Dhamma and not meant for commercial purpose or other low wordily gains by means of trade and exchange.]*